# Simple mail merge for google form

Tags: mailmerge

I am trying to modify the email template that is given by google's simple mail merge.  This is a google sheets that is linked to a Form response that i set to send me emails of the results when someone fills out my form.  My problem is that when i add an additional line under Email address for something like phone number, the results show right after the results for email.  It does not show it on a separate line.  Sorry if it doesn't make sense.  Hoping that someone that has used google forms and used mail merge with it will shine a light.  Thanks in advance.

The example is below.

```
Hi ${"First Name"}

Thanks you for signing up.  You submitted the following data:
First Name: ${"First Name"}
Last Name: ${"Last Name"}
Email Address: ${"Email Address"}

Please verify the information and contact us if there's any mistake.

Thank you!
```

If I add a different line like below :

```
Hi ${"First Name"}

Thanks you for signing up.  You submitted the following data:
First Name: ${"First Name"}
Last Name: ${"Last Name"}
Email Address: ${"Email Address"}
Phone Number: ${"Phone Number"}

Please verify the information and contact us if there's any mistake.

Thank you!
```

Results if another line of code is added under the email:
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Email Address : John.Doe@yahoo.comPhone Number:999-999-9999

Answer (score 0):

It could be a formatting issue. 
Do check that the paragraphing characters are the same (did you edit in the spreadsheet itself?)

Otherwise there should be no problems sending out. 
Do let me know if it works.